# can we apply declarative validation with DynaActionForm

Tags: java, struts-1, actionform

I am new to Struts framework.
I am getting a little confusion if DynaActionForm is not supporting validation why framework introduced this form bean class. As we have so many disadvantages like:

1. The DynaActionForm bloats up the Struts config file with the xml based
   definition. This gets annoying as the Struts Config file grow larger.
2. The DynaActionForm is not strongly typed as the ActionForm. This means
   there is no compile time checking for the form fields. Detecting them at
   runtime is painful and makes you go through redeployment.
3. ActionForm can be cleanly organized in packages as against the flat
   organization in the Struts Config file.
4. ActionForm were designed to act as a Firewall between HTTP and the
   Action classes, i.e. isolate and encapsulate the HTTP request parameters from direct use in Actions. With DynaActionForm, the property access is no
   different than using request.getParameter(some parameters).
5. DynaActionForm construction at runtime requires a lot of Java Reflection
   machinery that can be expensive.